# Connecting two SQL tables with Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the two tables below Table 1 and Table 2, I would like to get the `Sum` of the `FCount` in table two and group it by the `TID` and I would like to link it to table 1 where `table1.TID` matches `table2.TID` and select the data Where `Table1.ClientId=1` and `table2.ClientId=1`. I have tried the below and SQL tells me to group by all the individual fields and the no return

```
Table 1
id
ClientId
PageName
Country
CreatedAt
TId
TweetMessage
Replied
RCount
FavoritedCount
en_Media_type


Table 2
id
ClientId
Page
TID
UserIdFollower
screenName
Loc
FCount   

SELECT dbo.[tweets(ht)].clientid, 
       dbo.[tweets(ht)].pagename, 
       dbo.[tweets(ht)].country, 
       dbo.[tweets(ht)].createdat, 
       dbo.[tweets(ht)].tweetid, 
       dbo.[tweets(ht)].tweetmessage, 
       dbo.[tweets(ht)].replied, 
       dbo.[tweets(ht)].retweetcount, 
       dbo.[tweets(ht)].favoritedcount, 
       dbo.[tweets(ht)].en_media_type, 
       Sum(dbo.retweetersdata.followerscount) AS TotalFollowers 
FROM   dbo.[tweets(ht)] 
       CROSS JOIN dbo.retweetersdata 
WHERE  dbo.retweetersdata.tweetid = dbo.[tweets(ht)].tweetid 
       AND dbo.[tweets(ht)].clientid = 54 
GROUP  BY dbo.retweetersdata.tweetid
```

Comment: because u need to sum TotalFollowers, so the rest field must be in group

Comment: add some aggregate function on all other fields while selecting values if you want to avoid adding them all to group by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `INNER JOIN` instead of `CROSS JOIN`, and add the columns to `GROUP BY` that are not in an aggregate function:

```
SELECT     
  t.ClientId,  
  t.PageName, 
  t.Country, 
  t.CreatedAt,
  t.TweetId,
  t.TweetMessage, 
  t.Replied, 
  t.RetweetCount, 
  t.FavoritedCount, 
  t.en_Media_type, 
  Sum(d.FollowersCount) As TotalFollowers
FROM dbo.[Tweets(HT)] AS t
INNER JOIN dbo.RetweetersData AS d ON d.TweetID = t.TweetId
WHERE t.ClientId = 54 
GROUP BY t.ClientId,  
  t.PageName, 
  t.Country, 
  t.CreatedAt,
  t.TweetId,
  t.TweetMessage, 
  t.Replied, 
  t.RetweetCount, 
  t.FavoritedCount, 
  t.en_Media_type;
```